# PowerMock method intermittently invoking real method

Tags: java, powermock

I'm having a very strange problem with PowerMock, and I'm hoping somebody more familiar with its internals can suggest a next direction to chase.

The class under test is a Jersey Resource class.  The method being tested has a wait() statement in it, and it subsequently invokes 2 static methods on a Helper class.  When the first static method on the Helper class is invoked, the real method is executed, not mocked.

Nuances:

- if I invoke the static method before the wait, the Mocked response is returned.
- if I invoke the static method twice after the wait, the first time will execute the real method, and the second time will return the Mocked response.
- if I invoke the static method once before and 5 times after the wait, the invocation before the wait will return the mock response, the first invocation after the wait will execute the real method, and all subsequent invocations will return the Mocked response.
- if I debug it in my IDE debugger and put a break point on the method invocation, the mocked response is returned.
- if I comment out the wait(), everything is mocked as expected.
- all other mocking and stubbing and spying seems to be fine

I tried writing a test stub to demonstrate my problem to post here, but even I can't reproduce it on anything except the original class.  Unfortunately, I cannot post that class so I'm putting out this request for blind advice.

Why might a wait() cause a side-effect in PowerMock like this?

Not sure if this is relevant, but the wait() is due to a method invocation that would normally set up a callback.  I don't need the callback (not the point of my test), so I am simply mocking this method and no callback is set up.  Since there's no notify, the wait() is simply returning after the specified time limit.

In my test framework, I am using JerseyTest 2.14 (with Grizzly container), RestAssured 2.8.0, and PowerMock 1.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you are looking for but I have seen more than once that this is the better answer to any PowerMock problem: don't use PowerMock.
Even the folks developing it recommend to not use it.

When your production codes forces you to turn to PowerMock; then consider changing your production code. In other words: if you think you need PowerMock to test your code; then most of the time, that means you are dealing with bad design & implementation.

Seriously: PowerMock and its byte code manipulations can open a can of worms of problems. In the long run, you might better spend your time to redesign your "system under test" in order to make it testable using reasonable frameworks. For example, PowerMock breaks most frameworks for measuring code coverage. Something that might not hurt you today, but maybe will later on.

Comment: You're right:  this is good advice but not the advice I'm looking for.  While I hope that refactoring will be undertaken over time, I don't have much influence over the legacy code structure (and my deadline is next Thursday).  Practically, my options are to either get this working, or don't.